# DropzoneJS function instead of POST url

Tags: dropzone.js, oracle-adf

For a project that I am working on in IE11 and Oracle-ADF I am trying to implement DropzoneJS for a drag-and-drop upload feature the client requested.

Oracle-ADF exposes a Javascript API ([AdfFileUploadManager](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50629_01/adf/AFCJS/oracle/adf/view/js/util/AdfFileUploadManager.html)) which requires you to call addFileToQueue(Object file) to send files to the backend.

DropzoneJS however requires you to set a URL in the options (or use the standard form action) both of which do not seem to work in this scenario.
Is there any way in DropzoneJS to call this function instead of set a POST url?

Comment: I was searching for the exact same functionality. I am working with firebase storage which also exposes a JS API and no POST URL to call.

Answer (score 13):

If I understand your question correctly you want to use the DropzoneJS functionality without actually doing the upload?

In that case you should set `autoProcessQueue` to **false**. This will prevent Dropzone to automatically upload your file. Using the `addedfile` event, you can access the file object and use your other JS API to perform the upload.